# What difference has adding the self keyword made?

Tags: ruby, self

When I started learning Ruby, I started with Michael Hartl's excellent [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). I just revisited the tutorial and noticed that portions of the example application code were modified. In the authentication chapter two methods were changed:

```
# SessionsHelper
def sign_in(user)
  ...
  self.current_user = user
end

def sign_out
  self.current_user = nil
  ...
end
```

Previously, the keyword `self` was omitted. But the app worked. So, if it ain't broke, why fix it? What value has `self` added and why is it used?

I understand that `self` defines class methods as opposed to instance methods. And in models, using `self` allows us to reference an object's property directly. But I can't tie the dots and see how it's being used in a helper. I've seen it in controllers before and I can't understand why we would want to use it there.

Comment: If this worked without the `self` keyword, then they must have been using instance variables (b/c this invokes the setter method, but without the self, it would set a local variable). These are not the same thing, and IMO, it is much better to use the setting method than the instance variable (b/c setting the ivar directly means you have knowledge of it's implementation, but invoking the setter contains that knowledge to just one method).

Comment: @JoshuaCheek: not necessarily, there could be an `attr_accessor :current_user` or an explicit method `def current_user=(new_user)` and the same syntax would be valid.

Comment: There is indeed a method (in the new and old versions): `def current_user=(user) @current_user = user end`

Comment: @JoshuaCheek In my experience even if `current_user=` is defined without `self` Ruby will create local variable instead of using any methods.

Comment: @maerics no, it would set a local variable instead of invoking the setter. @VictorMoroz not sure what you mean, if you say `self.current_user=whatever` then you are invoking the setter, if you say `current_user=whatever` then you are setting a local var, so it must have previously been `@current_user=whatever`.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek Sorry, my comment above was addressed to maerics

Comment: @VictorMoroz: thanks for pointing out my mistake, I did not realize that you cannot omit the receiver of writer methods!  I wonder if the author of the tutorial did the same thing =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Edit]**

It is likely that the original section of the tutorial was just plain wrong.  Omitting the "self" receiver causes the methods to assign a value to the method local variable "current_user" with no other effect.

My original answer below is incorrect and should be ignored (because writer methods `foo=(x)` cannot be called without a receiver, as can other methods).

**[Incorrect Original Answer Below]**

<strike>The reason for using the "self" receiver is likely for clarity.</strike>

<strike>If "self" is omitted then, to the untrained eye, it looks like you are simply assigning the "user" variable to a new variable named "current_user" with no other effect.  Experienced Rubyists know that if there is a method named "current_user" on the object instance then it will be called instead of just creating and assigning a new variable but this detail can easily be overlooked, especially if the method is inherited or otherwise not declared in the current class definition section.</strike>

<strike>By using the "self" keyword explicitly you are clearly stating that you are calling a method on this object instance.</strike>

Comment: Really? If `current_user` is used without `self` in the left part of an assignment Ruby will create local variable instead of calling `current_user` method (even if `current_user=` is defined). Is it something I'm missing here?

Comment: -1. This is just plain wrong. `foo = bar` *always* assigns to the local variable `foo`. It will *never*, under no circumstance, send a `foo=` message. Never. You always *must* use an explicit receiver if you want to call a writer method. There is even an exception to the rule for `private` methods specifically for this reason. (`private` methods can only be called without an explicit receiver, writers can only be called with an explicit receiver, therefore it would not be possible to call a private writer, if the exception didn't exist.)

Comment: Ah, interesting.  Maybe this was 1.8 behavior?  I have also verified that in 1.9 this is *not* the case.

Comment: No, nothing of what you wrote has ever been true in any version of Ruby whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

```
class User
  attr_accessor :current_user

  def sign_in_1
    # Assigning local variable here
    current_user = "Foo"
  end

  def sign_in_2
    # Calling accessor method
    self.current_user = "Bar"
  end
end

u = User.new
u.sign_in_1
p u.current_user #=> nil
u.sign_in_2
p u.current_user #=> "Bar"
```